# Change array keys to specific strings

Tags: php

I am looking for a way to explicitly change some array keys as they will always be the same and the array length will always be the same and then output a single key based on the lowest value. Here is where I am at:

The array code itself look like this:

```
$t = array($low_score_1,$low_score_2,$low_score_3,$low_score_4,$low_score_5,$low_score_6,$low_score_7,$low_score_8);
```

Output example:

```
array(8) { [0]=> string(2) "11" [1]=> string(2) "15" [2]=> string(2) "13" [3]=> string(2) "12" [4]=> string(2) "18" [5]=> string(2) "16" [6]=> string(2) "16" [7]=> string(2) "14" }
```

So I want to change all 8 keys to each be a specific string. So I need to change the keys and then only output the key of the lowest value in the array. I can only at the moment output the value of the lowest in the array like so:

```
echo min($t);
```

And from the array above you can see that `11` is the lowest so that is the one I want to show BUT by ke and not value...

**UPDATE**

I have managed to set my keys and output both the keys with their retrospective pairs but I just want to show the lowest value by its key.

```
        $t = array(
        'a' => $low_score_1,
        'b' => $low_score_2,
        'c' => $low_score_3,
        'd' => $low_score_4,
        'e' => $low_score_5,
        'f' => $low_score_6,
        'g' => $low_score_7,
        'h' => $low_score_8,
        );

reset($t);
while (list($key, $val) = each($t)) {
    echo "$key => $val\n";
}
```

The output of this looks like:

```
a => 11 b => 15 c => 13 d => 12 e => 18 f => 16 g => 16 h => 14
```

Comment: And a downvote for what reason exactly? Its very clear in what my objective is AND I have made an attempt to get to my goal but I just need some advice... admin please explore why this has been downvoted...

Comment: Didn't downvote but It's a simple 'findMinimum' problem

Comment: @OfirBaruch how do you mean sorry? Im able to find the minimum no problem what I want to do is set the keys so 0 becomes score_1, 1 becomes score_2 and then output the kay instead of the value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned it's a simple 'find minimum' problem.
Only that you want to save the **key** of the minimum value.

```
        $t = array($low_score_1,$low_score_2,$low_score_3,$low_score_4,$low_score_5,$low_score_6,$low_score_7,$low_score_8);

  //Setting new keys        
$t2 = array();
    foreach($t as $key => $val){
     $key2 = 'score_' . ($key+1);
     $t2[$key2] = $val;
    }

//Finding the minimum
$min = $t2['score_1'];
$min_key = 0;

    foreach($t2 as $key => $val){
      if($val < $min){
        $min = $val;
        $min_key = $key;
     }
    }
        //output
        print_r($t2);
        echo $min; // the min value
        echo $min_key; // the key of the min value
```

Comment: I want to change the keys to specific string names, then just output the lowest value from the array but by its key and not by value.

Comment: Just a sec, checking something

Comment: fixed the code. Test the new code. **$min_key** will hold the key for the minimum value's key.

Comment: I need to set all 8 keys manually, At the moment your code is just settings the key to 0. So there will only ever be 8 in the array so key 0 needs to become the string 'score_1' etc

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Please edit your question and elaborate about it. What is the full desired output that you're looking for?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134294/discussion-between-phpdude-and-ofir-baruch).

Comment: Updated the solution.

Comment: Sorry, what I have provided answered your first question with the modified keys. You can use it as a basic code for whatever you want to improve.